# using vue from a different bundle

Tags: javascript, laravel, vuejs3, vite

I'm using Laravel + Vite + Vue3 + Inertia.
I want to have 2 separate Vite bundles for the same SPA
One to create the App and bootstrap it
and the second one to serve the actual Vue pages
a minified version of what i'm doing would be like this

app.blade.php

```php
    {{ Vite::useBuildDirectory('build/site')->useHotFile(public_path('hot-site'))
        ->withEntryPoints(['resources/builds/site/app.js']) }}

    {{ Vite::useBuildDirectory('themes/venus')->useHotFile(base_path('themes/venus/public/hot'))
        ->withEntryPoints(['src/app.js']) }}
```

site/app.js

```js
import {createInertiaApp, router} from '@inertiajs/vue3';
import {createApp, h} from 'vue';

window.createInstance = (resolveComponent) => new Promise(resolve => {
  // create app and bootstrap it
  createInertiaApp({
    resolve: resolveComponent,
      async setup({el, App, props, plugin}) {
          const vueApp = createApp({render: () => h(App, props)});
          // bootstraping...
          resolve({vueApp, el, router});
      },
  });
});
```

then in the theme/app.js

```js
const app = await createInstance(name => import(`./Pages/${name}.vue`));
app.mount(app.el);
```

But then everything is acting weird,
it seesm like vue and inertia cannot detect the
instance I'm getting issues like
inertia issue example
`this.resolveComponent is not a function`

vue issue example
`resolveComponent can only be used in render() or setup()`

I know this is a long one, any help would be appreciated, Thank you